Requests, how to download to a specific folder
i tried to save a picture with requests in a specific folder
So i got a code like this
urldwl = ""
filename = ""
def downloadimg():
    img_data = requests.get(urldwl).content
    with open(filename + '.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)

the "urldwl" and "filename" is definied after in the code, so the code in this form work perfetcly, i need to someone that can find me a way to save the file to a specific folder
thank

Does this answer your question? How to save a file to a specific directory in python?

If you just leave the with open("filenamejpg", "wb") as just a filename, it will save the file in whatever the current working directory is with that filename.
So if you are in C://Users/User/Documents/Project and run the above code, it will be placed like such C://Users/User/Documents/Project/filename.jpg
To choose a custom folder, you can either use an absolute path:
folder_path = "C://Users/User/Documents/Project/TargetFolder/"
with open(folder_path + "file_name.jpg", "wb") as file:...

Or, assuming your target folder exists in your working directory, a relative path:
# Assuming you are working in= C://Users/User/Documents/Project/"
folder_path = "TargetFolder/"
with open(folder_path + "file_name.jpg", "wb") as file:...

